# Object to array, type hinting does not work

Tags: php

I have this object from an API.

```
object(DotMailer\Api\DataTypes\XsInt)#62 (1) { 
        ["value":"DotMailer\Api\DataTypes\XsInt":private]=> int(16711) 
} 
object(DotMailer\Api\DataTypes\XsInt)#67 (1) { 
        ["value":"DotMailer\Api\DataTypes\XsInt":private]=> int(16722) 
} 
object(DotMailer\Api\DataTypes\XsInt)#73 (1) { 
    ["value":"DotMailer\Api\DataTypes\XsInt":private]=> int(16723) 
}
```

How can I convert it to an array?

I've tried:

```
$arr = (array) $apiResponse;
```

But I just get NULL.

Comment: What kind of output do you expect here? All attributes are private.

Comment: Do you mean this array of objects?

Comment: What about get_object_vars() function?

Comment: Are you sure you aren`t getting a json?IF so you can use json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of those `XsInt` objects, you should be able to just `echo` them. The `value` property is private, but `XsInt` has a `__toString` method that returns `value`. [See the DotMailer API client code here.](https://github.com/romanpitak/dotMailer-API-v2-PHP-client/blob/master/src/DataTypes/XsInt.php)

So, for one of those objects:

```
echo $theObject;
```

or if you have an array of those objects:

```
foreach ($array as $object) {
    echo $object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single object, you can just use `(array) $obj`.

If you have an array of objects, you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
class Foo
{
    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = 1;
    }
}

$foo = [new Foo, new Foo];
$array = array_map(function($item) {
    return (array)$item;
}, $foo);
```

Output:

> ```
> array(2) {
>   [0]=>
>   array(1) {
>     ["Foofoo"]=>
>     int(1)
>   }
>   [1]=>
>   array(1) {
>     ["Foofoo"]=>
>     int(1)
>   }
> }
> ```